# Are judges limited in their reasoning to arguments raised by the parties?

Tags: civil-procedure, common-law, judging, civil-judgment

Bob files a civil lawsuit agaist Rob. For simplicity, let's assume they both represent themselves.

At the hearing, Bob says: "*Here is the evidence. Rob was wrong because of reason A, so he owes me money.*"

Rob replies: "*Yes the evidence is true, but because of reason B reason A does not apply. I do not owe Bob anything.*"

Bob has nothing to add.

The judge proceeds making a judgment. Let's consider three alternatives:

1. He simply agrees with Rob: reason B indeed negates reason A. No questions here.
2. "*Here is reason C why reason B in these circumstances does not actually negate A as Rob contends, so Rob still owns money to Bob.*"
3. "*Reason B does indeed negate reason A as Rob contends. However, notwithstanding with that, here is reason D why Rob is nevertheless at fault, so he owns money to Bob.*"

In adversarial common law jurisdictions, will judgements 2 or 3 be inappropriate for a judge to make? **Are there rules in place that forbid judges from making judgements like either 2 or 3?**

As a very simple example, the above reasons A, B and C can be instanced this way:

- Bob's A: "*Rob went on red light so he is liable*"
- Rob's B: "*Yes I did, but that was right turn, which is allowed there*"
- Judge's C: "*Right turn on red is indeed allowed there but not on Sundays when the incident happened, therefore Rob is liable*".

Clearly, reason C was not raised by either party. Will the judge be allowed to not present it to Rob before delivering it in judgement?

This question has been induced by some statements made in feedback to [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/37054/why-would-a-party-to-civil-proceeding-suggest-amicus-curiae-counsel-assisting-t/37055):

By @phoog:

> Courts generally cannot consider arguments that aren't raised by a
>   party in the case.

By @Tim Lymington:

> It would clearly be unfair (as phoog says) for the judge to base his
>   judgment on his own research without giving either counsel a chance to
>   consider it

So, how do those statements stand when judge, merely applying the law, can't help generating a new argument that neither of the parties thought of?

Closely related: [If a judge constructs arguments for the prosecution in judgment is that grounds for appeal?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/19204/if-a-judge-constructs-arguments-for-the-prosecution-in-judgment-is-that-grounds)

Comment: It's really just the same as a referee in sports competitions - they can't get directly involved in the game either.

Comment: @MSalters that analogy breaks down fairly quickly if you consider the progress of the game to be analogous to matters of fact and the rules of the game to be analogous to law.  Players do not generally argue with the referee about what the rules of the game mean or how they are to be interpreted, but parties arguing before a judge do.

Comment: The answer is different in inquisitorial civil law jurisdictions and adversarial common law jurisdictions to some extent, and the question doesn't specify the jurisdiction so it is har to answer. There is no doubt that a judge can do so in an inquisitorial system. The question is less obvious in an adversarial one.

Comment: @ohwilleke Thanks for this point. Let's assume adversarial common law jurisdiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

Deciding a case on a basis the parties have not raised is a denial of natural justice (or procedural fairness) and invalid.

The reason is very simple, the parties have not had the opportunity to produce evidence or make submissions about C or D that might have changed the judge’s mind about them. Notwithstanding, to successfully appeal, the aggrieved party must show there were arguments that could have been raised which could reasonably have altered the outcome.

That said, it’s the judge’s courtroom and they can say “That’s interesting but what about C and D?” and then the parties can make submissions about them. They do have to be circumspect and make sure that they do not become one party’s advocate - one party might be well aware of C and D and don’t want them brought up because they damage their case and they are hoping the other party misses that - and then the bloody judge come charging in with his bloody duty to wider interests of justice.

Non-judicial decision makers like arbitrators, adjudicators and other tribunals need to be even more circumspect because they generally don’t have a duty to anyone but the parties.

Unlike in civil law systems, the role of the judge is to decide *the* dispute between the parties as a referee, not to determine some objective”truth” as an investigator.

To keep things simple: if the plaintiff contends that the light was red and the defendant contends the light was green then, assuming there is no evidence opening the possibility, it is not open to the judge to find that the light was amber. Similarly, if the parties agree that red means go and green means stop, it is not the judge's role to tell the parties they are wrong (I'm sure questions would be asked but if the parties are adamant ...): since there is no dispute over this issue the judge would be wrong to agitate one.

Now, a judge is free to apply the law that was argued as a whole - if arguments centred on Section 14 of the *Relevant Act 1875* but Section 15 is applicable and germane the judge is not wrong for applying Section 15. However, they are on shakier ground if the bring in *Other Slightly Relevant Act 1956*.

Comment: Naturally, to explain why A prevails over B (or other way around), one needs to come up with a reason that equals to neither A nor B. That will always be a _third_ reason. And judges do not normally discuss with parties why they choose A or B before delivering judgement: this will be _in_ the judgement, precluded with an analysis, right? This third reason, necessary to explain choice between A and B, is what I call C/D. Can you explain the line dividing C/D that the parties should be able to make submissions about, and C/D that is merely explains the judge's choice between A and B?

Comment: @Greendrake: This comment seems to redefine C and D; the question had other points C and D. The judge hears both A and B (arguments from both parties). He first needs to decide whether A holds up (evidence appropriate for the law cited, relief sought based in law). This is a judgment on A without bringing up B, C or D. Next is the decision whether argument B holds up. Again, B has to bring up laws and facts. Since this is apparently a counter-argument, the judge has to decide whether B in fact does counter A. If and only that is what the law says, then reason B wins.

Comment: @MSalters to decide whether A, B hold up you need a reason, correct? I don't see how the definition of C given in the question does not match the definition of a reason that B does not hold up. So  does my comment above actually redefine C? (I agree that D can't be used by the judge).

Comment: @Greendrake as you posed the question I see C as an extraneous cause. Naturally, the judge will decide if he accepts the evidence that supports A (and B) or not bearing in mind that there will be conflicting evidence. That is deciding on issues raised by the parties. To keep it simple: if the plaintiff contends the light was red and the defendant contends the light was green then it is not open to the judge to find it was amber (assuming no witness raised the possibility).

Comment: "assuming there is no evidence opening the possibility, it is not open to the judge to find that the light was amber." And if a witness claims that the defendant was drunk, but the defendant didn't present any rebuttal because being drunk was irrelevant to the cause of action presented, it would be unfair for the judge to rule on some cause of action that wasn't presented by the plaintiff for which the defendant being drunk is relevant. The defendant isn't obligated to present a defense against every possible claim imaginable, only the ones being asserted.

Comment: Say there's only one piece of evidence: Rob went on red light and noone disputes that. Bob's A: "_Rob went on red so he is liable_". Rob's B: "_Yes I did, but that was right turn, which is allowed there_". Judge's C: "Right turn on red is indeed allowed there but not on Sundays when the incident happened, therefore Rob is liable". Will the judge be allowed to not present this C to Rob before delivering it in judgement?

Comment: I would disagree. While a party may not argue a point not raised on appeal unless one of the parties or the judge raises it, usually a judge can reach a legal conclusion not offered by either party even in an adversarial common law system, and also on appeal a trial court ruling will be upheld if there is any legal theory upon which the conclusion could be correct, even if the reasoning for the result actually given by the judge is wrong, even if not party argued it. The modern rule is also to allow a judge to grant relief not asked for originally by a party if it is not a default judgment.

Comment: If a judge grants judgment on a ground not raised by either party, either party may dispute that reasoning in a post-trial motion for a new trial or for reconsideration, so it does not violate natural justice (at least in a civil case, the analysis is more rigid in a criminal prosecution).

Comment: "Non-judicial decision makers like arbitrators, adjudicators and other tribunals need to be even more circumspect because they generally don’t have a duty to anyone but the parties." Arbitration awards are generally upheld even if the arbitrator is definitely incorrect about the law and usually aren't subject to appeal of any kind.

Comment: Judges in appellate courts routinely rule for reasons advanced very specifically by either party. I've seen this happen several times in the last few years alone. For example, in a case where a party put no case law in an appellate brief and the court ruled based upon a precedent decided only after oral arguments were complete found by a law clerk for a judge and not argued by either party (a motion for reconsideration was brought as a result and denied).

Comment: @ohwilleke denial of procedural fairness is one of the few grounds an arbitrator can be appealed on.

Comment: @DaleM There is no way that an arbitrator would ever be overruled on grounds of procedural fairness simply because he or she decided to resolve a dispute between a legal theory not offered by either party. The most common ground for reversal of an arbitration is refusing to allow a party to submit relevant evidence before a decision is made, but if that is done and there is no bribery or undisclosed conflict of interest, arbitration awards are basically never reversed. Basically an effort to overturn an arbitration award needs to be on a ground that doesn't involve reading the award itself.

Comment: On the other hand, in an adversarial system, a judge does never consider evidence that isn't supplied by either party that isn't in the narrow class of facts subject to judicial notice (and often not even then as many kinds of judicial notice must be requested by a party). Arbitrators generally aren't even held to this rule and usually can consider extraneous evidence.

Comment: @ohwilleke Are we talking at cross-purposes due to differing standards between our jurisdictions? I agree that a judge will go beyond the strict limits of the law that was argued but if the parties agree that the dispute is about contract law only the judge would be wrong to engage an equitable remedy.

Comment: @ohwilleke Not to mention that in some cases a judge *must* independently determine something even if the two parties actually agree on it (subject-matter jurisdiction springs to mind).

Comment: @ohwilleke with respect to Arbitration, [2-0600] of the NSW Civil Trials Bench Book says "There is no relief from an award by way of appeal, new trial or judicial review, unless relief is
sought on the ground of lack of jurisdiction or a denial of natural justice: s 41 of the CPA." https://www.judcom.nsw.gov.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Civil_Trials_Bench_Book.pdf

Comment: @ohwilleke similarly [2-6700] explicitly calls out procedural fairness as a ground for appeal: In relation to civil proceedings the same principle applies: DJL v The Central Authority, above, per
Callinan J, at [189]; Miltonbrook Pty Ltd v Westbury Holdings Kiama Pty Ltd (2008) 71 NSWLR 262
at [85]–[87]. But with the qualification that different considerations may arise in civil proceedings,
as where questions of status or the rights of third parties are involved: R v Lapa (No 2) (1995) 80
A Crim R 398 at 403, cited in Burrell at [25].

Comment: @DaleM "Are we talking at cross-purposes due to differing standards between our jurisdictions?" Quite possibly. The non-reviewability of arbitration awards in the U.S. is very extreme. Procedural fairness would be much narrower than you suggest in the U.S., natural justice would be almost beyond consideration (I mean, maybe if the arbitrator declared that somebody should be burned at the stake for using U.S. mail instead of FedEx or something). And arbitrators in the U.S. usually determine their own jurisdiction in the first instance subject to review only after the entire process is complete.

Comment: @ohwilleke Australian domestic arbitration law is based on international arbitration rules - sounds like the US, as in many things, blazes it’s own trail.

Comment: Of course, if the SCotUS bases a ruling on points not raised, there's not a thing anybody can do about it; but that goes for pretty much everything the high court does.